# How many consumer instances should you create per node thread?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Are there any use cases (performance etc.) to instantiate multiple consumers within a single node.js thread?

Comment: consumers of what?  What do you mean by "consumer instance"?  That is not a standard node.js term.

Comment: @jfriend00 If you look at the tags, this question relates to Apache Kafka, where "consumer instance" is a standard term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to create several consumer instances *in one thread*, given that a consumer tends to block further execution until it is stopped.

I'd take a look at the [Kafka Consumer Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers), as they explain why you'd want to use more than one consumer in the first place.